# regular expression for сross tags

Tags: regex

How can I get the "**qwerty.**" data between the tag [p][/p] (without any other TAG, only plain text [a-zA-Z_-,.*\x20]) with using a single **regex** expression from this string:

```
[m1][p][i][c][com][lang id=1049]**qwerty**.[/i][/p] [i]и[/i] [p][i]**gf**.[/lang][/com][/c][/i][/p][/m]
[m1][p]**qwerty**[/p]
[m1][c][com][lang id=1049]\[-дэр\] [p][i]**м**.[/lang][/com][/c][/i][/p][/m]
[m1][p][i][c][com][lang id=1049]**q1**.[/p] [p]**q2**.[/p] [p]**q3**.[/p] [p]q4[/lang][/com][/c][/i][/p][/m]
```

If I use

```
(?<=\[p]).*?(?=\[/p])
```

I get :

```
[i][c][com][lang id=1049]qwerty.[/i]
```

and

```
[i]gf.[/lang][/com][/c][/i]
```

but I need to get the "**qwerty.**"

Comment: What application are you using?  `awk`? `sed`? `php`?

Comment: notepad++, emeditor, python, java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option could be matching the `[p]` followed by matching square bracket pairs that do not start with `[p]` or `[/p]` at the left and right and capture any char except square brackets in a capture group.

```
\[p](?:\[(?!/?p])[^][]*])*([^][]+)(?:\[(?!/?p])[^][]*])*\[/p]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[p]` Match `[p]`
- `(?:\[(?!/?p])[^][]*])*` Optionally repeat from `[` till `]` when not starting with `[p]` or `[/p]`
- `([^][]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ times any char except `[` and `]`
- `(?:\[(?!/?p])[^][]*])*` Optionally repeat from `[` till `]` when not starting with `[p]` or `[/p]`
- `\[/p]` Match `[/p]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e0yXtO/1)

Or using Notepad++ you could make use of `\K` to clear the match buffer and get a match only.

```
\[p](?:\[(?!/?p])[^][]*])*\K[^][]+(?=(?:\[(?!/?p])[^][]*])*\[/p])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Go2brE/1)

Comment: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 60
\[p](?:\[(?!/?p])[^][]*])*([^][]+)(?:\[(?!/?p])[^][]*])*\[/p]

Comment: @AliaksandrShpak In java you have to double escape the backslashes and escape the square bracket.

Comment: @AliaksandrShpak `String regex = "\\[p](?:\\[(?!/?p])[^\\]\\[]*])*([^\\]\\[]+)(?:\\[(?!/?p])[^\\]\\[]*])*\\[/p]";` See https://ideone.com/EWy0D0

Answer (score 1):

This captures your target in group 1:

```
\[p](?:\[.*?])*?([^\[]+?)(?:\[.*?])*?\[/p]
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/etTnpQV4OHd29G).

It works by consuming opening and closing tags either side of the target, which is restricted to non-brackets, and using reluctant quantifiers throughout.

Comment: i mistook with example, your code will not work with another line

Comment: @AliaksandrShpak OK. Try the new version.

Answer (score 1):

Hello try this short regex, it may help

Find what: `^.*?p\]\*\*(.*)\*\*\[|.*\s?`
Replace with: `$1`

The first group (.*) will match any random words located in between
[P]** **[p/] and the rest everything will be removed ....

Comment: "qwerty." is a random text

Comment: They want to match between `[p]` & `[/p]`. Your regex, appart it search only `qwerty` doesn't take care of this constraint.

Comment: @Toto  does my updated regex is working with notepad++ , saw no reaction from you?

Comment: in "qwerty. can be any content

Comment: [doesn't seem to work](https://regex101.com/r/5gcOwd/1), look at [@thefourthbird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66651798/372239) answer.

Comment: @ aliaksandr  sure (.*) will capture any content you intended for ... just once try it....

Comment: The example text you put in web regex101 had no ** before and after QWERTY, but here in your example it does